# Redis - There is no way to migrate from a AOF-disabled environment to a AOF-enabled environment?

Tags: nosql, redis

Basically my situation is as follows:

1) I've initially started Redis without AOF, and had it running for **n** weeks.

2) I decided that I want to use AOF, so I restart Redis & turn on AOF after **n+1** weeks.

3) I decided that I want to move to a new server. So I safe-shutdown the current Redis process, and copy the RDB file and the AOF file over to my new server.

4) When I start Redis in my new server with AOF turned on, the default behavior of Redis is to load data *ONLY* from AOF. **This means that my data during the first n weeks are lost.**

Of course there is the obvious solution of starting Redis without AOF so that the data is loaded from the RDB, then turning on AOF while it's running.

But this pretty much means that **there is no way to use AOF if you even had a slight period where your AOF was turned off, and you can only utilize AOF if you've been using it continuously since day 1.**

Is this understanding correct? If so, it sounds pretty useless for anybody who wants to migrate to an AOF-enabled environment. And a system that has no means of migration sounds pretty lame.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to include your past data into your AOF file?

I would appreciate some help, since this affects my decision of whether I even need AOF in my environment. (Which means I cannot experience the great benefits of AOF...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how AOF works.

AOF is actually two mechanisms:

- a redo-logging mechanism which appends all write operations to the AOF file
- a background rewrite operation which can generate an AOF file from the content of memory

The background rewrite operation is triggered periodically by Redis, but you also have the possibility to use the [BGREWRITEAOF](http://redis.io/commands/bgrewriteaof) command to start it manually.

Now, when the AOF is dynamically turned on through the "config set appendonly yes" command, a rewrite operation is automatically triggered, so you can be sure all existing data are part of the generated AOF file.

You can see this code in the aof.c file:
https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/aof.c#L192

In the situation you described, you should get all your data in the AOF file.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly as you said, I have been misunderstanding the background rewrite operation. After the rewrite operation is triggered, my dataset was all safely inside my AOF, and I was able to start my server only with a AOF file. I thought `BGREWRITEAOF` was just a compression mechanism of the existing AOF file, but I was wrong. http://redis.io/topics/persistence#append-only-file  This page also explained it.  I appreciate your explanation very much :)

Comment: Why does [Redis in Action - 4.1.3 Rewriting/compacting append-only files](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-4-keeping-data-safe-and-ensuring-performance/4-1-persistence-options/4-1-3-rewritingcompacting-append-only-files/) say *To solve the growing AOF problem, we can use BGREWRITEAOF, which will rewrite
the AOF to be as short as possible by removing redundant commands.*? Seems like the rewriting is based on the original AOF file. Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

In any case, the best practice with redis is never stopping a server and copying files to another server. The best practice is start redis on the new server as a slave of your current one and just let redis do all the synchronization.

You can configure the slave to accept writes, but so far all your clients are still pointing only to the old master.

Then when everything is synchronized, you point all your clients to the slave. The slave will have the same data as the master, and since it is accepting writes, your clients can set new keys if they want.

At this stage, the old server is not receiving any requests, so what you can do now is dynamically change the slave and say it's slave of none. That way it will stop communicating with the master for synchronizing. If you change this dynamically, don't forget to persist the config file to disk.

After this step, your old master is totally isolated. No clients are talking to it and no slaves are synchronizing. You can just stop it.

See? you got zero downtime and no messing with files manually :)

In any case, you should read Didier comment. He's right about AOF

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have brought up the migration example in order to clarify my understanding of the AOF file, so server migration wasn't my primary concern.  But your migration tip sounds very promising and simple; I'd definitely use that next time I have to move servers! Thanks a lot!